# design automation older engines

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Is there any plan to support older versions of the engines? My potential use case would be automated creation of testing files to be used in data compliance checks against forge model-derivative. Ea. does our data still process the same in older versions (potentially to be used in CI, so that we can also test the other side of the equation, does Forge still output the same data?)

Answer (score 1):

Generally we are looking forward to supporting newer engine versions.  That said, we would be interested in hearing which older engine versions you'd like supported.  Please let us know which products - Revit, Inventor, AutoCAD, or 3dsMax - you want the versions for too.

Best,
Michael

Comment: Yeah I figured newer engines would be covered automatically. This would mostly be for engines of Autocad/Civil3d between 2013-2018. Revit potentially too, but I'm less sure how much older versions are still being used.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check all the supported engine versions by the endpoint [GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/engines](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/engines-GET/).

But as Michael mentioned, we will mainly support the newer engine versions, there might be a less chance to support old version like 2013-2018 as far as I know, but you can always let us know your request and reason, and we can forward to our engineering team if this confirms to be a reasonable request.

Answer (score 0):

The official support of AutoCAD goes back **3 releases**.

If you inspect the response from  [GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/engines](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/engines-GET/) you'll see that we have engine version posted going back to AutoCAD 2016 ("Autodesk.AutoCAD+20_1"). This is because the cost of removing old engines is higher than the cost saving that their removal would bring. This can obviously change and you should expect that we will remove older engines as we see customers stop using them.

We have no plans to post earlier engines.